# How can I create an instance of an object on mouse click where the cursor is in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new to coding. I'm trying to make a simple game where you can left click to spawn a salt "molecule" and right click to spawn a water one where the mouse cursor is. I don't know how to spawn a molecule where the mouse cursor is. I've been trying for a couple of days now.

```
//I've tried this:
Texture textureSalt;
textureSalt.loadFromFile("graphics/salt.png");
Sprite spriteSalt;
spriteSalt.setTexture(textureSalt);
spriteSalt.setPosition(/*I don't know what to put here; how to get it to spawn where the mouse is.*/)
```

Please help and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getPosition()` function inside the Mouse class to retrieve the current position of the mouse cursor.

```
const sf::Vector2i mousePosition = sf::Mouse::getPosition();

// Convert the Vector2i, containing the mouse position, to a Vector2f since the setPosition function doesn't accept Vector2i
spriteSalt.setPosition(sf::Vector2f((float)mousePosition.x, (float)mousePosition.y));
```

Comment: When I do that, it gives me an error. I think it's because the getPosition function doesn't qualify as a parameter for setPosition, because it accepts only two floats. Is there any way I can express the getPosition as two floats? The error is "no instance of overloaded function sf::Sprite::setPosition matches the argument list"

Comment: @ElijahCampbell Yeah, I realized now that the setPosition function in the Sprite class only accepts either a sf::Vector2f or two floats, and not sf::Vector2i (which the getPosition function in the Mouse class returns). I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: That seems to have worked. I don't have an error anymore. Thank you!